# Disable LAN in Beetel router

Tags: wireless-router, lan

I have a wireless internet connection via a Beetel router (which supports wired LAN too). I want to disable LAN access through the router even if the Ethernet cable is connected.

What I have done till now:

1. Opened 192.168.1.1 in the browser
2. Logged in
3. Clicked on the LAN tab
4. Now what do I do next?

Screenshots of my web interface:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Most routers don't have those kinds of features. I have only seen that kind of thing on managed switches. Also becareful, the wireless may use the lan settings for IP scoping (defining the Internal subnet). if there is not a way to assign an internal subnet for the WIFI components, then they rely on each other.

Comment: I disagree, most routers have abilities to do such thing, usualy not from web interface. Try to `telnet 192.168.1.1` or if you don't have telnet, get [putty.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Post type of your router.